# How do I close the standard output and standard error on Erlang?

Tags: erlang, stdout, stderr

I have tried several things such as `file:close(standard_io)`, `file:close(standard_error)` and `{ok, Fd} = file:open(standard_io, []).` [1](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/io.html#type-device) to no avail.

---

The effects of this are the following (in `python` for illustration):

```
python3 | sed -E 's/a/b/g'
```

```
Python 3.8.10 (default, Mar 15 2022, 12:22:08)
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print('a')
>>> b
import sys
sys.stderr.close()
sys.stdout.close()
>>> >>> >>>
>>> print('a')
>>>
>>> exit()
```

Notice that `>>> b` was actually output by `sed` and once the `stdout` was closed no more data flowed through it.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on practical benefits of closing stdout/stderr at run-time?

Comment: One is abstraction: `stdin`/`stdout` can be treated as a regular file. This allows implementations and services further down the stack the treat both equally. Other is correctness. Sometimes programs might want to read input to a certain point and ensure nothing is written/read to it. Conversely, I cannot see a good reason why this would not be the case (I'm open to ideas though).